# Getting selected values from multiselect in Laravel with multiple-select jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using [wenzhixin/multiple-select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/) as it has select all option. I'm trying to get selected items ticked that were selected while creating the post.

This is what i have done but it doesn't work.

```
{{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') }}
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple" id="tags">
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{$tag->id}}">{{$tag->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

---

```
<script>
    $("#tags").multipleSelect({
        placeholder: "Tags please"
    });
    $('#tags').multipleSelect().val({!!json_encode($post->tags()->getRelatedIds() )!!}).trigger('change');
</script>
```

I would  be thakful if anyone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting selected values from a multiple select form in Laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358227/getting-selected-values-from-a-multiple-select-form-in-laravel)

Comment: I think you should use something like `$('#tags').multipleSelect('setSelects', [1, 3]);` instead of `$('#tags').multipleSelect().val()`

Comment: @GilleQ. the thread you have linked hasn't used jquery plugin.

Answer (score 1):

At the end of the day, it's just an HTML select element. Given the name of `tags[]`, this will submit within the form and be accessible through a controller as `$request->get('tags')` or if using the helper, then `request()->get('tags');`

Furthermore, you can pass the selected items to the next page in this way:

```
public function myFunctionToHandleTheForm()
{
    $tags = App\Tag::all(); //for example, no idea what you use
    $selectedTags = request()->get('tags');

    return view('my.view', compact('selectedTags', 'tags');
}
```

Now, `$tags` will be a numerically ordered array (ascending) containing the `ID's` that were submitted from your form. You can set the defaults that were checked just like this:

```
{{ Form::label('tags', 'Tags:') }}
<select name="tags[]" multiple="multiple" id="tags">
    @foreach($tags as $tag)
        <option value="{{$tag->id}}" {{ in_array($tag->id, $selectedTags) ? 'selected="selected"' : null }}>{{$tag->name}}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

In the above, we're checking if the tag id is in the list of `selected tag id's`, and if so, we're setting the `selected` attribute. Your plugin will understand this and translate it correctly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Your code shows only selected tags only. I want all tags to be displayed and tick the selected ones only. If incase user wants to user wants to change tags for the post.

Comment: Previously i used select2 jquery plugin for handeling tags. And above mentioned code worked perfectly with it. I switched to  multiple-select as it has select all option.

Comment: @ZacharyDale My code does exactly what you state. It loops `all tags` and selects `only the ones that were previously selected`. This leaves the ones that were *not* selected *unchecked*.